# MongoDB lookup and unwind not giving correct results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have Product model which contains list of all products of different sellers and Order model which contains list of ordered products

I need to make a query, getting total amount earned by a seller

**Products Model:**

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "ProductName": "product 1",
  "Price": 100,
  "SellerId": 1
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "ProductName": "product 2",
  "Price": 200,
  "SellerId": 2
},
{
  "_id": 3,
  "ProductName": "product 3",
  "Price": 50,
  "SellerId": 1
}
```

**Orders Model:**

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "ProductId": 1,
  "Price": 100,
  "Quantity": 2,
  "Total": 200,
  "Status": true
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "ProductId": 2,
  "Price": 200,
  "Quantity": 10,
  "Total": 2000,
  "Status": true
}
```

**Aggregation**

```
db.products.aggregate([
   {
     "$match": { "SellerId" :1 } 
   },
   { 
    $lookup: { 
      from: 'orders', 
      localField: '_id', 
      foreignField: 'ProductId', 
      as: 'requests.service'
    } 
  },
  $group:{
     _id: "$_id",
     totalAmount: { $sum: "$Total" },
  }
])
```

The final output shows 0 when searching for a particular seller, not able to figure out the solution.

Expected output for seller 1 is 200 and for seller 2 is 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're filtering with "SellerId" :1 . This is not correct.

Secondly you need to unwind requests.service.
For $unwind aggregation you can find info here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Your query must be like this:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "ProductId",
      as: "requests.service"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$requests.service"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$requests.service.Total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "totalAmount": 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/t4MfjgcyxXx

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` operator produces an array field, you need to `$unwind` the new field before the `$group` pipeline to get the desired result. `$unwind` deconstructs the array field. so `{$unwind: "$requests.service"}` note the dollar sign `($)` in front of the `$requests.service` before you group will do the work